# How to check if a string contains spaces/tabs/new lines (anything that's blank)?

Tags: c++

I know there's an "isspace" function that checks for spaces, but that would require me to iterate through every character in the string, which can be bad on performance since this would be called a lot. Is there a fast way to check if a std::string contains only spaces?

ex:

```
function("       ") // returns true
function("    4  ") // returns false
```

One solution I've thought of is to use regex, then i'll know that it only contains whitespace if it's false... but i'm not sure if this would be more efficient than the isspace function.

```
regex: [\w\W] //checks for any word character(a,b,c..) and non-word character([,],..)
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: _"that would require me to iterate through every character in the string, which can be bad on performance"_  How do you expect to test whether all characters matches your criteria _without_ iterating over all the characters in the string?

Comment: Don't worry about micro optimization until your solution is in working order.

Comment: To my knowledge it's not actually possible to see if a string contains spaces without checking if every character is a space, it can't be done any quicker, except when you find a non-space you return false there and then instead of checking the rest of the string.

Comment: You could look at the system time before and after calls with each function to determine which is faster.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Any* method would, of necessity, need to look at each character of the string. A loop that calls `isspace()` on each character is pretty efficient. If `isspace()` is inlined by the compiler, then this would be darn near optimal.

The loop should, of course, abort as soon as a non-space character is seen.

Answer (score 10):

With a regular string, the best you can do will be of the form:

```
return string::find_first_not_of("\t\n ") == string::npos;
```

This will be O(n) in the worst case, but without knowing else about the string, this will be the best you can do.

Comment: this is not necessarily the best you can do. See my comment.

Comment: `if (b) return true; return false;` should just be written `return b;`.

Comment: @PreetKukreti With a regular std::string. If you wanted to implement your idea, you'd need to either wrap a std::string in another class like cached_string or something similar. If this is an option then by all means your idea is faster.

Comment: @Yuushi yes, that is the idea. As I said, it really depends on if it is worth the complexity, which most likely it isnt :)

Comment: It's actually O(n) in the average case too. In fact it is θ(n) average case.

Comment: it looks this answers the opposite, one needs to use `return string::find_first_of("\t\n ") != string::npos;`

Answer (score 2):

You are making the assumption regex doesnt iterate over the string. Regex is probably much heavier than a linear search since it might build a FSM and traverse based on that.

The only way you could speed it up further and make it a near-constant time operation is to amortize the cost by iterating on every update to the string and caching a bool/bit that tracks if there is a space-like character, returning that value if no changes have been made since, and updating that bit whenever you do a write operation to that string. However, this sacrifices/slows that speed of modifying operations in order to increase the speed of your custom `has_space()`.

Comment: Nit:  `isspace` has constant time complexity because it only tests a single character.  A loop testing each character with `isspace` would have linear complexity.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis ah. I thought it was a string operation. Will update. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, a locale has a function (scan_is) to do things like this:

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {

    std::string inputs[] = { 
        "all lower",
        "including a space"
    };

    std::locale loc(std::locale::classic());

    std::ctype_base::mask m = std::ctype_base::space;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        char const *pos;
        char const *b = &*inputs[i].begin();
        char const *e = &*inputs[i].end();

        std::cout << "Input: " << std::setw(20) << inputs[i] << ":\t";
        if ((pos=std::use_facet<std::ctype<char> >(loc).scan_is(m, b, e)) == e)
            std::cout << "No space character\n";
        else
            std::cout << "First space character at position " << pos - b << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's probably open to (a lot of) question whether this gives much (if any) real advantage over using `isspace` in a loop (or using `std::find_if`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use find_first_not_of if you all the characters to be in a given list.
Then you can avoid loops.

Here is an example

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str1="      ";
    string str2="      u    ";
    bool ContainsNotBlank1=(str1.find_first_not_of("\t\n ")==string::npos);
    bool ContainsNotBlank2=(str2.find_first_not_of("\t\n ")==string::npos);
    bool ContainsNotBlank3=(str2.find_first_not_of("\t\n u")==string::npos);
    cout << ContainsNotBlank1 <<endl;
    cout << ContainsNotBlank2 <<endl;
    cout << ContainsNotBlank3 <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
1: because only blanks and a tab
0: because u is not into the list "\t\n "
1: because str2 contains blanks, tabs and a u.

Hope it helps
Tell me if you have any questions